# Excel VBA: Merge/combine strings with same starting characters

Tags: vba, excel

I could not work on any solution and did not find an answer online, maybe you can help me

I would like to merge 2 cells in VBA as the following:
cell1: `foo_123`
cell2: `foo_456`
outputCell: `foo_123_456`

So the code should see that cell1 and cell2 have `foo_` in common and delete the `foo_` part of cell2

the output would look like something like this:
`outputCell = cell1 & "_" & cell2`
(outputCell = foo_123 & "_" & 456)

Comment: How is your data structured (fixed lenght etc.) and what did you try?

Comment: is there a particular pattern to the match at the start? i.e. is it if the first 3 characters always match? Also, is VBA really the best option here. within the sheet you could do something like: =IF(LEFT(A1,3)=LEFT(A2,3),A1&SUBSTITUTE(A2,LEFT(A1,3),"")) where A1 is foo_123 and A2 is foo_456

Comment: @Jochen The start of the string is not a fixed length (e.g. alarm_ relay_ or temperature_), JensS has found the solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple function that should do the trick (I have used Strings, not cells, and depending on your data, you may wish to add some corner cases, but the general idea should be clear):

```
Function merge(value1 As String, value2 As String) As String
    Dim result As String

    result = value1

    For counter = 1 To Len(value2)
        If Len(value1) < counter Then ' Edit SLT: changed <= to <'
            result = result & "_" & Mid(value2, counter)
            Exit For:
        Else
            If Not Mid(value1, counter, 1) = Mid(value2, counter, 1) Then
                result = result & "_" & Mid(value2, counter)
                Exit For:
            End If
        End If
    Next

    merge = result
End Function
```

Comment: This works perfect! Now I tested the code on multiple cells I had only one minor issue, alarm_on and alarm_off becomes alarm_on_ff, but I will find a workaround for that

Comment: result = Replace(result, "on_ff", "on_off") 
merge = result